# Cannot figure out how to use a class component method in a different component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I started learning React this week and am having issues understanding how to use a component method inside another component. I'm trying to move the buttons from below the visualizer and into the Navbar. The "Generate New Array" button works below the visualizer but not in the Navbar and Im having a hard time understanding why. I think it has something to do with updating the state in Button.js or Navbar.js so Im reading into that now, but I would appreciate if someone could explain the issue while I am searching for the solution. Thank you !

[sorting algorithm visualizer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nnoif.png)

Navbar.js

```js
import React from "react"
import icon from "./images/sort.png"
import Button from "./Button"

export default class Navbar extends React.Component {
    
    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="nav--bar">
               
                <h1 className="nav--text">  <img src={icon} className="nav--icon" />Sorting Algorithm Visualizer</h1>
                <div className="nav--buttons">
                    <Button 
                            name="Generate New Array"   
                            handleclick={() => this.props.resetArray()}
                        />
    
                        <Button 
                            name="Merge Sort"
                            handleClick={() => this.mergeSort()}
                        />
    
                        <Button 
                            name="Quick Sort"
                            handleClick={() => this.quickSort()}
                        />
    
                        <Button 
                            name="Insertion Sort"
                            handleClick={() => this.insertionSort()}
                        />
    
                        <Button 
                            name="Bubble Sort"
                            handleClick={() => this.bubbleSort()}
                        />                        
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }   
}
```

Button.js

```js
import React from "react"

export default class Button extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                {/* BUTTONS Note: all css classes except for button-sort come from tachyons */}
                <button
                    className="button"
                    onClick={this.props.handleClick}
                >
                    {this.props.name}
                </button>
            </div>
           
        )
    }
}
```

Visualizer.js

```js
import { render } from "@testing-library/react"
import React from "react"
import "./Visualizer.css";
import Button from "../components/Button";



// Make responsive on all screens
const screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
const screenHeight = window.innerHeight;


let animationSpeed = 1; // animation speed
if (screenWidth < 700) {
  animationSpeed = 3;
}

export default class Visualizer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)


        this.animationSpeed = animationSpeed;
        this.numberOfBars = screenWidth / 10;
        this.primaryColor = "orange";
        this.secondaryColor = "white";
        this.barHeight = screenHeight - 500;

        this.state = {
            array: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        //on initial load or page refresh
        this.resetArray();
    }

    resetArray() {
        //reset array with randomly generated numbers
        const array = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.numberOfBars; i++) {
            array.push(getRandomNumber(5, this.barHeight));
        }
        this.setState({ array });
    }    

    render() {
        const { array } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="array--container">
                {array.map((value, index) => (
                    <div className="array--bar" key={index} style={{ height: `${value}px` }}></div>
                ))}

               <div className="">
               <Button 
                    name="Generate New Array"
                    
                    handleClick={() => this.resetArray()}
                />
                <Button 
                    name="Merge Sort"
                    handleClick={() => this.mergeSort()}
                />
                <Button 
                    name="Quick Sort"
                    handleClick={() => this.quickSort()}
                />
                <Button 
                    name="Insertion Sort"
                    handleClick={() => this.insertionSort()}
                />
                <Button 
                    name="Bubble Sort"
                    handleClick={() => this.bubbleSort()}
                />
               </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
    
}

export function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import Visualizer from "./Visualizer/Visualizer";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Info from "./components/Info";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Visualizer />
      <Info />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Where are all these methods defined? I can see only the `resetArray` implementation.

Comment: Where and how did you try using the `<Navbar />`? What props did you pass?

Comment: Are you getting an error? What "does not work" about it?

Comment: i have not implemented the other methods as of right now. No errors, in the app. The only button that is finished and functional is the bottom "Generate New Array" button. I am trying to get the top "generate New Array" button to work, and then will delete the bottom buttons.

Comment: I am using the <Navbar /> component in my App.js which I just in the post

Comment: There is no way to call the `<Visualiser />` methods from the `<Navbar />` if they are side-by-side. Just don't do that. Put the `<Navbar … />` inside the `Visualiser`, and pass the methods down via props, just like you're currently passing them directly to the buttons.

Comment: why exactly is that not possible? I was able to fix it after reading your comment so thank you!